# FSA - prepay installment plan for orthodontics - okay on flexible spending account?

Tags: united-states, taxes, fsa, benefits

Let's say $2,000 is still owed on an orthodontic payment plan which is set to have monthly payments of $250/mo.

Assuming there is $2,000 left available on an FSA, can it be used to pay off the rest?

In case the context is helpful, at the start of the treatment, assume that the payment options were to pay in full or to make monthly payments, and the treatment occurs starting at that point and then continuing concurrently with the monthly payments, though the two may end at different times.

Comment: Not sure what it is that you're asking. If it's a qualified expense for the plan, then sure.

Comment: @littleadv okay so there's no problem stemming from electing to pay it faster than otherwise required? I assume not but thought it worth confirming. Thanks

Comment: The concern for installment plans is that the only the FSA plan year during which the treatment occurred can be used.  You can't pay for treatment across year boundaries.  I'm not familiar with the rules for an ongoing series of treatments but it's plausible that the cost would have to be split between "treatments performed in 2022" and "treatments performed in 2023".  You can't use the 2022 FSA to pay for treatments planned for 2023.  And you can't use the 2023 FSA to pay for treatments already performed in 2022... even if they are billed in 2023.

Comment: _SOME_  FSA administrators will accept SOME prepay as expense in the year it was paid; more often you have to amortize that across the years when service is received. Contact whoever runs yours and ask (and)or try to argue with) their answer... but you are probably going to have to do the paperwork.